# What's an inexpensive way to connect 3 sites over VPN, each with dynamic IPs?

Tags: amazon-ec2, vpn, openvpn, ipsec

I have 3 networks that I would like to connect to each other over VPN (IPSec or OpenVPN).

Each site has a single dynamic public IP address and is running NAT.

How can I connect each of the sites together?

I was thinking there might be some kind of VPN service I could run in the cloud (EC2)?

Comment: Other than Coldmin already answered:
You could rent a VPN service somewhere, which most likely makes it more easy to adminiser, however you can never be sure it is actually only connected to your other sites (Trust etc.)
Your other option can be: build a VPN server to be hosted in a datacenter (search for colocation). Do not underestimate the amount of work you need to administer the server/services correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Use a dynamic DNS service.
2. Get a hostname for each site.
3. configure VPN connections to use hostname for each connection instead of the sites IP address (Since you said its dynamic and subject to change)

The dynamic DNS service should come with an application that monitors for an IP address change, and updates the hostname record automatically.

Comment: this is possible without additional costs.

Comment: That's good to know.  The only free one I was aware of was no-ip.com - the update client is free, and they have free hostnames.  However, this can open you up to attack using the free domain/hosts because they are well known, probed for vulnerabilities frequently.

Comment: True that there is possible more security issues involved, however these days everything on the internet get scanned often, so you should have good security.
Additionally: if you have your own DNS somewhere you can go with that aswell.